# Oracle: DBCA stucks when creating new database: getcrshome execution failed

Tags: oracle

I reinstalled, Oracle 11, now I try to create a new database using DBCA with admin user.
But on the latest step after I press finish, it stucks with error;

```
 PRCT-1400 : getcrshome execution failed. Detailed error:
localnode
  at oracle.cluster.cmdtools.GETCRSHOMEUtil.getCRS_HOME(GETCRSHOMEUtil.java:161)
  at oracle.cluster.cmdtools.GETCRSHOMEUtil.getCRS_HOME(GETCRSHOMEUtil.java:112)
  at oracle.cluster.deployment.ClusterwareInfo.getConfiguredCRSHome(ClusterwareInfo.java:422)
```

Comment: Off topic but: Do not use the character set named UTF8 as the database character set unless required for compatibility with Oracle Database clients and servers in version 8.1.7 and earlier, or unless explicitly requested by your application vendor. Despite having a very similar name, UTF8 is not a proper implementation of the Unicode encoding UTF-8. If the UTF8 character set is used where UTF-8 processing is expected, data loss and security issues may occur. This is especially true for Web related data, such as XML and URL addresses. Oracle recommends AL32UTF8

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe sorry I alredy meant AL32UTF8, tnx for warning

Comment: Did you check dbca logfile?

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe where can i find it?

Comment: Probably : $ORACLE_BASE/cfgtoollogs/dbca/trace.log

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe no error in the file

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe it says in the beginnign that  _WS_ Failed to delete Service OracleRemExecService on PCiT-213 acces denied

Comment: http://joordsblog.vandenoord.eu/2012/03/oracleremexecservice-available-windows.html. So OracleRemExecService is probably still running from a previous dbca session. Can you reboot server? And try again

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe now i have: Failed to create service "OracleRemExecService" on node "PC-iTi-213", Error: "Access is denied.

Comment: and Could not find file(s) "ORAUTS.DLL"

Comment: Are you running dbca as an administrator? Try to start cmd as an administrator and then run dbca. Or switch to linux ;-)

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe it helped(I had to reinstall oracle btw) but now it got stuck saying getcrshome execution failed